# RecycleView Nested on a ViewPAge

Tags: android-recyclerview, nested, android-viewpager2

I am new on android App developtment.
Somebody know how to nest RecycleView into ViewPager2?

I need to group the male and female items in separate pages. The itens are on the WEB. So on ViewPager2 page 0 I will list all males itens, and on page 1 all female items.

Inititally I am calling on MainActivity the Viewpager2 adapter. Inside this adapter I am using the onBindViewHolder method to call the RecycleView adapter.

It is working well, however the second page of ViewPager2 is not being populated since its adapter position is changing from 0 to 1 and imediately from 1 to 2 when I swipe the Viewpager2 from position 0 to  1.

Thanks.